# How to remove Next and Previous button from SimpleExoPlayerView in Android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use ExoPlayer to play audio on my Android App with SimpleExoPlayerView as the controller. The default controller have five button, Play/Pause, Forward, Backward, Next, and Previous. My app only use Play/Pause, Forward, and Backward, so I want to remove the Next and Previous button from the controller but I couldn't find how to do it with the SimpleExoPlayerView. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need a custom layout `exo_playback_control_view.xml` file which is what `exoplayer` looks for by default for inflating the control view. **It is important that the custom layout is named `exo_playback_control_view` and that certain `id`s are used**

**The default controls can be seen in the source code [here release-v2](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml) or [here dev-v2-r2.3.1](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/dev-v2-r2.3.1/library/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml)** (Make sure you find the version of `exoplayer` which you're using)

You can copy that file into your `res/layout` directory, and remove the undesirable buttons, here is what the default looks like:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>
```

---

There is also a [post](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a) on medium which is a big help for customizing `exoplayer`; the author writes a custom control:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="#CC000000"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="#CC000000"
  style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice the `id`s are **required**

Comment: I tried to create a new layout named exo_playback_control_view.xml. Because I only need to remove next-prev button, so I just copied from original xml file and remove the tag I don't need. But, when I execute my app I got Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar.

I use Proguard, but since it's on debug, I think it shouldn't be a problem isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, does the app run? Is there something wrong with the time bar?

Comment: The link you provided is not the same as my version. So I need to copy from the same version tree. Now it's fixed, thanks.

Comment: What version is it? Can you share the link?

Comment: I use version 2.3.1 and I see it inside my Android Studio inside External Libraries, under project name.

Comment: This method doesn't work at all in current versions I am afraid.

Answer (score 31):

There are default styles for each button. Just override the styles of Previous and Next buttons and add visibility gone.

 **Put below styles in your style.xml**

```
<style name="ExoMediaButton.Previous">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>

<style name="ExoMediaButton.Next">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i tried findViewById(R.id.exo_prev).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.exo_next).setVisibility(View.GONE); didnt work this one sure did!

Comment: Short and clean

Comment: This indeed hides the buttons, however they are still there, and when user taps on their position, they will work as intended - which is probably NOT what people reading this answer would like to achieve..

Answer (score 6):

the PlayerView class of exoplayer has two methods to hide those

```
    playerView.setShowNextButton(showNextPrevButtons)
    playerView.setShowPreviousButton(showNextPrevButtons)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in your style.xml

```
    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Previous">
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Next">
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Simple and smooth.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the visibility of buttons is changed dynamically
So it's better to set zero size of them to fully hide

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_shuffle"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Shuffle"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_repeat_toggle"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen"
        android:src="@drawable/fullscreen"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/exo_vr"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

**SimpleExoPlayer** deprecated. You should use **StyledPlayerView** in this version:

`'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'`

Short answer:

```xml
 argType:show_next_button="false"
 argType:show_previous_button="false"
```

Long answer: You can hide and show other buttons in a similar way.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:argType="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        argType:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        argType:show_buffering="when_playing"
        argType:show_fastforward_button="false"
        argType:show_next_button="false"
        argType:show_previous_button="false"
        argType:show_rewind_button="false"
        argType:show_subtitle_button="true"
        argType:use_artwork="true"
        argType:use_controller="true">

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's worked:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should `hideControl()`, I also do it.

1. Create `CustomSimpleExoPlerView` like `SimpleExoPlayerView`.
2. Comment all line have `showControl()`.
3. Set `CustomSimpleExoPlayer` in xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
StyledPlayerView playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_prev).setVisibility(View.GONE);
playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_next).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This is worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with this, It works fine for me

```
            ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
            StyledPlayerView styledPlayerView = viewHolder.binding.idExoPlayerVIew;
            MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(message.getVideoUrl());
            styledPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            styledPlayerView.setShowNextButton(false);
            styledPlayerView.setShowPreviousButton(false);
            player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
            player.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two methods for removing Next and Previous buttons from a player:

```
playerView.setShowPreviousButton(false);
playerView.setShowNextButton(false);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post